# ¿Cómo pasar arrays a una función y cómo retornarlos?

Tags: c++, array, funciones

Tengo el siguiente código quisiera saber cómo es la manera correcta de mandar arrays a una función, en este caso un método, y cómo regresarlas. Aun no sé usar puntero, pero logré que regrese la dirección de los arrays que mandé al inicio, pero no sé como ver el array origina.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class conjunto {
public:
    int* getConjunto1();
    int* getConjunto2();
    void setConjunto1(int cadena[10]);
    void setConjunto2(int cadena2[10]);
private:
    int Conjunto1[10];
    int Conjunto2[10];
};

int* conjunto::getConjunto1() {
    return Conjunto1;
}
int* conjunto::getConjunto2() {
    return Conjunto2;
}
void conjunto::setConjunto1(int cadena[10]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        Conjunto1[x] = cadena[x];
    }
}
void conjunto::setConjunto2(int cadena2[10]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        Conjunto2[x] = cadena2[x];
    }
}
int main(){
    conjunto obj;
    int conjuntoX[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int conjuntoY[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int* x;
    int* y;

    obj.setConjunto1(conjuntoX);
    obj.setConjunto2(conjuntoY);

    x = obj.getConjunto1();
    y = obj.getConjunto2();  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Primero: las formaciones<sup>1</sup> no se comportan como esperas.

Las formaciones en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) son un tipo de datos con un comportamiento particular, se les aplica una regla especial conocida como *decaimiento a puntero*, que en términos generales viene a decir que si pasas una formación a una función ésta se transformará en puntero, veámoslo:

```
void f(int i[10])
{
    for (int x = 0; x != 10; ++x)
        std::cout << i[x] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int b[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    f(a);
    f(b);

    return 0;
}
```

[El código anterior](https://tio.run/##ZY7NDoJADITP9CnGeABiTcR/BX0R5YALmk10IbAYEsOzY1dPxtO0M@3kU1U1vSk1DGNt1L3NCyS6bGxdZI8j0bPUOa6BNhb6FM3SkF7kXcsaH6vDAbNYZHRAJMNk0oXkeY3N93tVthZJIm9d6tSHH9Nv5J@NeD2R63pk2gSferdlp1Uq5a@IMWcsGEvGqo@/4cWR/KWMNWPD2DJ2LDhyLahBFsZOLqFb68K2tRFm6ofhDQ) genera la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5 32767 0 0 4199088 0 
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> ```

Se supone que la función `f` recibe un parámetro `int i[10]` pero ha aceptado sin rechistar el argumento `a` que es `int a[5]` ¿Cómo es posible?.

#### Segundo: Decaimiento a puntero.

Si añadimos un chivato a la función `f` para que nos de más información:

```
void f(int i[10])
{
    std::cout << "Llamada a " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
        << " con el argumento: " << i << '\n';
    for (int x = 0; x != 10; ++x)
        std::cout << i[x] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

La salida pasa a ser:

> ```
> Llamada a void f(int*) con el argumento: 0x7ffd90ad5510
> 1 2 3 4 5 32765 0 0 4199200 0 
> Llamada a void f(int*) con el argumento: 0x7ffd90ad54e0
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> ```

Vemos que no se ha conservado la información de tamaño del parámetro de `f`, lo que ha sucedido es que el parámetro `int i[10]` ha decaído a puntero para transformarse en `int *i`.

#### Tercero: referencias a formaciones.

Para evitar esto, debemos pasar la formación como referencia:

```
void f(int (&i)[10])
{
    std::cout << "Llamada a " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
        << " con el argumento: " << i << '\n';
    for (int x = 0; x != 10; ++x)
        std::cout << i[x] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int b[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    f(a);
    f(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Ahora el código no compila y se queja de la primera llamada a `f`:

> ```
> In function ‘int main()’:
> error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int (&)[10]’ from expression of type ‘int [5]’
>   f(a);
>     ^
> note: in passing argument 1 of ‘void f(int (&)[10])’
>  void f(int (&i)[10])
> ```

Si no hacemos la primera llamada, [la salida es](https://tio.run/##ZVBdS8MwFH1ufsVxgmtZZKs6P9rOF1EQZIrUB6mlZGk3Am0yulQKo7@9Ju3T8CU35557zj0J3@8vd5z3/bmQvGzyApFQB10XrHok5FeJHFtXSA33QniJv0g9ciTOQedBwFWjEUWYvJWsYjkDw8TiLPv4fI7j7@zla/0Uv76vs4w4jh0EVxJFCVbvmqqQWgWjQthj@iOnIXG2qsawsMUKi9CUsxV8c5nNWs/4nKwWSZsOWljpCTXadYRYr4oJ6Q7JLWLJMjXmR5/iiuKa4oZi2YUjubGP/MdS3FLcUdxTPFATx0wTZz43f8M8G9rdeLZTF7qppYlNur7/Aw):

> ```
> Llamada a void f(int (&)[10]) con el argumento: 0x7ffdd7c5af90
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> ```

#### Propuesta.

Define la formación de diez enteros como tipo interno de tu clase `conjunto`:

```
class conjunto {
public:
    using conjunto_t = int[10];

    conjunto_t &getConjunto1();
    conjunto_t &getConjunto2();
    const conjunto_t &getConjunto1() const;
    const conjunto_t &getConjunto2() const;

    void setConjunto1(const conjunto_t &cadena1);
    void setConjunto2(const conjunto_t &cadena2);
private:
    conjunto_t Conjunto1;
    conjunto_t Conjunto2;
};

int main()
{
    conjunto obj;
    int conjuntoX[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int conjuntoY[10] = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

    obj.setConjunto1(conjuntoX);
    obj.setConjunto2(conjuntoY);

    std::cout << "Primer conjunto: ";
        for (const auto &x : obj.getConjunto1())
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "Segundo conjunto: ";
        for (const auto &x : obj.getConjunto2())
        std::cout << x << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZLdboJAEIWv2aeY2EQlmRp3/Qfbm75Ak97UtE2Dy5as0YXAYtoQn90uoqgoNikXBM7MmW93ZngU3Qecb7d3UvFl6guYyjDRsfBWj4TwpZckwEO1SJUOISNROl9K7hArTaQKysinhgeQSr/R7odLiHWiNwOhn/a/tG1DBrHQaaygFF3Y1DrYNQc7OBINN0hFQj2v3s3q3Ts2sdah9CE55V0W5J4vlEdtYmWQaN9xeBj9tHdfcxFI1T4kYBEWyq9KRV4Jse3d2atwVgtnf8HZJZxdh7MCHsVy7WnhEDDP6dSO7SXXZOaSjdkMsyOw8kxZm2THPAjnC2PLgwfpNV8ls1QZRYY97OMAhzjCMU6QdjeV5FmZTJEypD2kfaQDpEOkI6RjpBNkuYtYhtSpzq0A2u5FlJXRmZ2b941MNUyn0HiO5UrE5SEcaLhFV77CGPYj8VJzu@Y3OPkVO@cLamZzXvE7f7Wg5VZIrXd1oTVeRJAqP/wnnt3EE2u/9V0zte32Fw)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Al declarar este parámetro: `int (&i)[10]`, el identificador `i` internamente es un puntero o no?

Comment: No, el parámetro es literalmente una referencia a una formación de diez enteros.

Comment: Es algo interesante. Tanto el parámetro `int (&i)[10]` y `int* i` genera el mismo código ensamblador, esto quiere decir, que en realidad `i` guarda la dirección base del arreglo y por ende, es un puntero (claro si hablamos a nivel de implementación).

Comment: El cómo acabe en el binario es cosa del lenguaje ensamblador, en el lenguaje [tag:c++] `int (&i)[10]` es una referencia a una formación de 10 enteros y `int *i` es un puntero a entero.

Comment: Nadie dice lo contrario (las referencias y punteros en C++ son diferentes). Mi duda no era hacia C++, sino más bien en como funciona (por eso usé el término "internamente").

Comment: Interna y externamente, a nivel de [tag:c++] una referencia es una referencia y un puntero es un puntero. El cómo eso se traduzca una vez compilado o cómo lo trate cada compilador, no tiene que ver con la especificación del lenguaje.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es correcto, así es como se retornan y envian arreglos, para ver el arreglo lo que tienes que hacer es iterar en la variable a la cual se lo estas asignando, en este caso:

```
x = obj.getConjunto1();
y = obj.getConjunto2();

for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    cout<<x[i]<<" - "<<y[i]<<'\n';
```

Otra forma de enviar arreglos es:

```
void seeArray(int *array, int tam){
    for(int i = 0;i<tam;i++)
        cout<<array[i]<<'\n';
}
```

En este caso solo se define que la función recibira un puntero (Los arreglos son punteros), y también recibe el tamaño del arreglo para iterar o generar operaciones con el. Si la función que estas haciendo es para un método especifico donde tu conoces el tamaño del arreglo que recibes puedes omitir la variable del tamaño, un ejemplo con tu código:

```
void setConjunto2(int *array){
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
        conjunto2[i] = array[i];
}
```

Comment: No es así como se envían o devuelven arreglos. Lo que estais haciendo es trabajar con punteros, no con arreglos.